# Find all $Hom(\mathbb Z/m ,A) $, A- finite Abelian group

Tags: group-theory

My attempt: 
I want to prove that $Hom(\mathbb Z/m, A) \simeq A$

Let's build map $k$: $f \to f(1)$. It's a group homomorphism:
$fg \to g(f(1)) = g(a) = g(1+1+..+1) = g(1)a=ba=f(1)g(1) $

$k$ is injective and surjective hence bijective.

Comment: did you mean $A$ and not $A/mA$?

Comment: yes, the task was for any Abelian finite A. But now, I started to understand that the task is simlar to that: $Find Hom (\mathbb Z/mZ, \mathbb Z/nZ)$, am I right?

Comment: Any abelian group is a $\Bbb Z$ module

Answer (score 1):

Your conjecture is clearly false, I'm afraid: for $m=2$ and $A=\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, the only homomorphism is the zero one.

Consider instead $A(m)=\{x\in A:ma=0\}$

If you use multiplicative notation on $A$, $A(m)=\{x\in A:x^m=1\}$

Comment: Hi egreg, you mean $\{a \in A: ma=0\}$?

Comment: @IgorKozyrev I assume $A$ is written additively, which makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

A less confusing way to put the question is as follows:

- Question: Let $m \in \Bbb Z$ and  $C_m$ the cyclic group of order $m$, $A$ a finite abelian group, describe the group of homomorphisms $f : C_m \rightarrow A$ with group composition defined by $(f*g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$.
- Answer: Let $a \in C_m$ be a generator of $C_m$ and $f$ any homomorphism, then $f$ is completely determined by the value $f(a)$. But since $a^m = e$ and $f(e)=0$
  one must have that the (additive) order $f(a)$ is a divisor of $m$ so $\operatorname{Hom}(C_m,A) \cong G$, The subgroup of A consisting of elements with an order a divisor of $m$.
- Examples: With $A = \Bbb Z_2 \times  \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_6 \times \Bbb Z_{30}$ and $m = 6$ we have $G = \Bbb Z_2 \times  \Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_6 \times \Bbb Z_6$. On the other hand for $m = 5$ we have $G = \Bbb Z_5$.
- Exercise: Calculate $G$ in the cases $m = 2,3,4$.